# Oracle - Grant Create Job privilege to role

Tags: oracle

Oracle - Grant Create Job privilege to role

```
Login user = JOEL

User JOEL got error "ORA-27486: insufficient privileges ORA-06512: at 
"SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 124 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 271 ORA- 
06512: at line 1"
```

---

To resolve the above error, grant JOEL the following privilege:
    Grant Create Job to JOEL;
Remarks: By granting Create Job to JOEL, this resolved the error above.

---

```
But, instead of granting "Create Job" directly to user JOEL, grant the 
privilege by ROLE as follow:

Create Role Job_Role;
Grant Create Job to Job_Role;
Grant Job_Role to JOEL;

Remarks: User JOEL got the same error even granted with Job_Role
```

May i know why granting role is not working?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you edit your post and add the SQL statement that cause the error message you got?

Comment: Also please show whether the statement that causes the error is being run inside an anonymous PL/SQL block or inside a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will not work with the privilege `CREATE JOB` granted via a role, as stated in the documentation:

> *"Object privileges must be granted directly to the user."*  ([source](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_SCHEDULER.html#GUID-ECF750C2-5ED1-4AFA-92C8-4617156414F3))

As to why Oracle implemented it that way, one can only guess that `DBMS_SCHEDULER` is implemented at least partly in a PL/SQL package. Inside stored procedures of all kind, roles are (in)famously disabled.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback

Comment: Your welcome! Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. You'll get points and others now whether your question has been answered sufficiently.